# Error with DropDownList MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this code in my Controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> objResult = new List<SelectListItem>();
        Models.Countries country = new Models.Countries();
        DataTable result = country.GetAllCountries();

        foreach(DataRow row in result.Rows)
        {
            objResult.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = row["country"].ToString(),
                Value = row["id"].ToString()
            });
        }

        ViewBag.country = objResult;
        return View();
    }
```

and then within my view I have:

```
@model Project.Models.CountryViewModel
@Html.DropDownList("country", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.country, "Select")
```

And then I render this partial view within another view:

```
@model Project.Models.Register
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Register", "Register", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "complete"}))
{
  <div id="complete">
  @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Countries.cshtml, new Project.Models.CountryViewModel()")
  </div>
}
```

Within CountryViewModel I have:

```
public int CountryID { set; get; }
public string country { set; get; }
```

However I get this error:

> Additional information: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'country'.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Just copied and pasted your code it worked fine.

Comment: looks like your error from another part of View

Comment: @teovankot The DropDownList is within a Partial View, are you saying other View's are interferring?

Comment: It depend on how you load your partial View. If you load it with ajax - not. But if you using something like `@RenderPartial` - could be

Comment: Is your partial view strongly typed to some class ? Are you passing something to the partial view ? Show us the relevant code please

Comment: @Shyju I updated my question

Comment: Your code still works for me ! Your problem is somewhere else !

Comment: @Shyju I don't understand where it is getting that error from, their is no where else

Comment: The error means that `ViewBag.country` is `null`. Possibly because you submit the form and return the view but did not reassign the value of `ViewBag.country` property as you did in the GET method.

Comment: @KTOV, I have marked this as a duplicate because the answer explains how to solve the issue. You get a slightly different error message because you have multiple other errors in your code. you cannot name the property your binding to the same as the `ViewBag` property you assign the `SelectList` to (rename the `ViewBag` property to say `CountryList`) but you really should be using a strongly typed view model anyway i.e. you view model contains a property `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>  CountryList`.

Comment: You next problem is you bind the selected value (which is the `id` property of `Country` which I assume is `int`) to the `string country` property of your model. I assume you want to bind it to the `CountryID` property, and your model should not contain `string country`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The render the partial view as

```
@Html.Partial("_YourPartialViewName", Model)
```

not like

```
 @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Countries.cshtml, new Project.Models.CountryViewModel()")
```

You have give pass the `Model` object as in above code, then only the dropdown renders correctly.
Then Change the code as below in the controller

```
ViewBag.country = new SelectList(objResult, "Value", "Text");
```

Then in the partial view page

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.Models.CountryViewModel>
@Html.DropDownList("country", ViewBag.country as SelectList, "Select")
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: dude try the updated code

Comment: Im still getting the error :/

Comment: show the `Register` model please